# Dimensions too large in pgfplots graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, intersections

I exported some code from GeoGebra but I get the error "dimensions are too large." I have narrowed the error down to these two lines

```
\draw [samples=50,domain=-0.99:0.99,rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},xshift=0.cm,yshift=0.cm,line width=1.2pt] plot ({1.*(1+(\x)^2)/(1-(\x)^2)},{4.*2*(\x)/(1-(\x)^2)});

\draw [samples=50,domain=-0.99:0.99,rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},xshift=0.cm,yshift=0.cm,line width=1.2pt] plot ({1.*(-1-(\x)^2)/(1-(\x)^2)},{4.*(-2)*(\x)/(1-(\x)^2)});
```

What can I do to fix this? The full code is here:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.6666666666666667cm,y=0.625cm]
\tikzset{every pin edge/.style={thin}}
\begin{axis}[
x=1.667cm,y=0.625cm,
restrict x to domain*=-3:3,
restrict y to domain*=-1:7,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-3.0,
xmax=3.0,
ymin=-1.0,
ymax=7.0,
xtick={-3.0,-2.0,...,3.0},
ytick={-1.0,0.0,...,7.0},]
\draw [samples=50,domain=-0.99:0.99,rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},xshift=0.cm,yshift=0.cm,line width=1.2pt] plot ({1.*(1+(\x)^2)/(1-(\x)^2)},{4.*2*(\x)/(1-(\x)^2)});
\draw [samples=50,domain=-0.99:0.99,rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},xshift=0.cm,yshift=0.cm,line width=1.2pt] plot ({1.*(-1-(\x)^2)/(1-(\x)^2)},{4.*(-2)*(\x)/(1-(\x)^2)});
\draw [line width=0.4pt,domain=-3.:3.] plot(\x,{(-4.250947801416127-3.538296784708813*\x)/-2.387670622927252});
\draw [line width=0.4pt,domain=-3.:3.] plot(\x,{(--9.300005586137612-4.239726050759403*\x)/2.861000632961514});
\draw [line width=0.4pt,domain=-3.:3.] plot(\x,{(-4.250947801416127-3.538296784708813*\x)/-2.387670622927252});
\draw [line width=0.4pt,domain=-3.:3.] plot(\x,{(-4.250947801416127-3.538296784708813*\x)/-2.387670622927252});
\draw [line width=0.4pt,domain=-3.:3.] plot(\x,{(--9.300005586137612-4.239726050759403*\x)/2.861000632961514});
\draw [line width=.4pt,dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (0.5,-1.) -- (0.5,7.);

\addplot[mark=*, color=black] coordinates {(-1.7794648702694271,5.887607628941302)} node[pin={[ultra thick,pin distance=10pt]0:{$A$}}]{};
\addplot[mark=*, color=black] coordinates {(1.384964676131416,3.8327580756041426)} node[pin={[ultra thick,pin distance=10pt]135:{$Q$}}]{};
\addplot[mark=*, color=black] coordinates {(1.081535762692087,1.647881578181899)} node[pin={[ultra thick,pin distance=10pt]0:{$B$}}]{};
\addplot[mark=*, color=black] coordinates {(-1.0027059467958361,0.2944612908953296)} node[pin={[ultra thick,pin distance=10pt]160:{$P$}}]{};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I' go for @Zarko's solution, but the large dimensions (two of them) are in the curves. Changing both domains from `domain=-0.99:0.99` to domain=0.97:0.97`worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would draw your diagram on the following way:

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} % recent is 1.18
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      dot/.style = {circle, fill, semitransparent, inner sep=2pt},
every pin/.style = {pin edge={black, shorten <=1pt}, pin distance=10pt}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
    x=1.667cm,y=0.625cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-3,    xmax=3,
    ymin=-1,    ymax=7,
    ytick={-1,0,...,7},
    axis on top,
    grid,
    ticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize},
    domain=-3:3, samples=101, no marks,
                ]
\addplot [red, thick, name path=A1]  ({+sqrt(1+\x*\x)},4*\x);
\addplot [red, thick, name path=A2]  ({-sqrt(1+\x*\x)},4*\x);
%
\addplot [blue, name path=B1]  coordinates {(-1.9,-1) (3.0, 6.2)}; 
\addplot [blue, name path=B2]  coordinates {(-2.5, 7) (2.8,-1.0)};
%
\draw[dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt] (0.5,-1) -- (0.5,7.);
%
\path [name intersections={of=A2 and B2, by=x}]
        node[dot, pin=180:$A$] at (x) {};
\path [name intersections={of=A2 and B1, by=x}] 
        node[dot, pin=180:$P$] at (x) {};   
\path [name intersections={of=A1 and B1, by=x}]
        node[dot, pin=  0:$Q$] at (x) {};
\path [name intersections={of=A1 and B2, by=x}]
        node[dot, pin=  0:$B$] at (x) {};
%\node[dot, pin=180:$A$]   at (-1.779464870269427, 5.887607628941301) {};
%\node[dot, pin=  0:$Q$] at ( 1.384964676131416, 3.832758075604143) {};
%\node[dot, pin=  0:$B$]   at ( 1.081535762692087, 1.647881578181899) {};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The cause of your error is in the way, how your function is draw. If you replace `draw plot ...` by `addplot` compilation works fine, but result is wrong (due to definitions of your functions). Therefore I redefine/approximate  your function by square root function and draw lines separately. Points of their intersections are determined by help of `intersections` library.